# Preact-Router - Handle routes from sub directory

Tags: router, preact

I'm currently creating a SPA that can be included and run from any route.

Currently any `<Link />` component I create redirects the client back to the root of the domain it's on plus the intended path.

In `react-router` there's a property to set a starting base path; `basename`.

This doesn't seem to be present in `preact-router` and I'd really rather not switch to `react-router` as it's significantly larger and I won't be using many of the additional features.

A simple example of the routes:

```
<Router>
  <Route
    path="/"
    component={Home}
  />
  <Route
    path="/:slug"
    component={Merchant}
  />
</Router>
```

I've seen a couple of post around the internet implying this is possible but with such little documentation it's a little tricky to piece together.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've ended up wrapping the `preact-router` `Link` and `Router` with my own components. From there I can prefix the `path` property value with my apps base route, e.g:

```
<MyRoute
   path="/"
   component={Home}
/>
```

Then somewhere within `<MyRoute />`:

```
const route = 'my/app/base/path';

let result = (route || '') + this.props.path;

result = result.replace(/([^:]\/)\/+/g, '$1');
```

Then render the `preact-router` default component with the result value, `<Route path={result} />`

Comment: Would you be able to add a little more clarity here?  What is the preact-router default component you're referring to?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for hash routing, here it is: https://github.com/developit/preact-router#custom-history.

Answer (score 0):

jhdevuk's Answer pointed me to the right direction.

The following Router class will do the trick (this is in TypeScript):

```
    class SubfolderRouter extends preactRouter.Router {

        render(props: preactRouter.RouterProps, state: any) {
            if (state.url.indexOf(MY_FOLDER) == 0) {
                state = {
                    ...state,
                    url: state.url.substr(MY_FOLDER.length),
                };
            }
            return super.render(props, state);
        }
    }
```

If your app lives in the folder `const MY_FOLDER = "/myfolder"`, then this Router will ignore the folder of the URL. If the user navigates to

```
/myfolder/home/index
```

then the Router will look up the URL `/home/index`, because this is the actual route.